# Tail -f search file with * match and latest date time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tail

I am trying to tail the latest file in a directory that matches a name.

Below example doesn't work

```
tail -f | ls -t /var/log/impala/impalad.demo.local.impala.log.INFO.* | head -1

tail: warning: following standard input indefinitely is ineffective
/var/log/impala/impalad.demo.local.impala.log.INFO.20180322-104843.43442
```

What is the best way to tail `impalad.demo.local.impala.log.INFO.*` that has latest time on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
tail -f $(ls -t /var/log/impala/impalad.demo.local.impala.log.INFO.* | head -1)
```

instead. `tail` expects a file to read from, which you obtain with `ls -t /var/log/impala/impalad.demo.local.impala.log.INFO.* | head -1`. Piping follows an `input | output` pattern, though, so your current scheme won't get you far. Piping the filename into `tail` won't work either because `tail` doesn't expect filenames from standard input. To pass a filename to `tail` you must pass it as an argument.